# Can't open .lnk file

Tags: microsoft.ink

How do you make a .lnk usable? I saved my documents folder which is where I keep important things to both my GDrive and a thumb drive and in both places it turned into an .ink file. The most luck I've had opening it is that I get to look at all my foldes but they are empty.

I've tried opening it, I've tried reinstalling Winrar because I did sve it as a Zip also and I've tried seeing if I could convert it with Zamzar.